# populating HTML Radio buttons from code behind in C#

Tags: c#, html, dynamic, radio-button

I am generating radio buttons from Code Behind in the following code

```
                      var licRB = questions[QNo - 1].AnswerRadioButton.optionRB;
                    for (int i = 0; i < licRB.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (licRB[i]._checked == "true")
                        {
                            stringBuilder.Append(String.Format("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Q" + (QNo) + "AnswerRBOption\" value='{0}' title='{1}'  checked=\"checked\" />{1} <br />", licRB[i].value, licRB[i].text));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            stringBuilder.Append(String.Format("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Q" + (QNo) + "AnswerRBOption\" value='{0}' title='{1}'  />{1} <br />", licRB[i].value, licRB[i].text));
                        }
                    }
                    (FindControl("divQ" + QNo + "AnswerRBL") as HtmlGenericControl).InnerHtml = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

On submit button click the value selected is stored in the db as follows:

```
 ARBValue = Request.Form["Q" + QNo + "AnswerRBOption"],
```

Now I need to retrieve the value from the DB and show the radio buttons with the selected value. Pls let me know best way to do this?

Comment: what error do you face in this code?

Comment: there is no error! I want to know a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below text resolves the issue of showing the selected radio button in the HTML5 radio button list

```
   (FindControl("divQ" + q.QNo + "AnswerRBL") as HtmlGenericControl).InnerHtml = q.ARBOption
                    .Replace("checked=\"checked\"","")
                    .Replace("value='"+ q.ARBValue + "'" , "value='" + q.ARBValue + "' checked=\"checked\"");
```